# En la página de perfil de usuario, cambiemos "N %" por "N%" al indicar el porcentaje "superior general"

Tags: bug, estado-completado, perfil, diseño

En [mi página de usuario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui?tab=profile) se ve ahora mismo algo así como:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fijaos en el texto, con un espacio entre "12" y "%":

> **12 %** superior general

El Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas, en su sección [números](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=QHaq7I8KrD6FQAyXTS) indica que:

> c) Los porcentajes superiores a diez: En las últimas elecciones votó el 84% de la población. **No debe dejarse espacio de separación entre el número y el signo %**. Hasta el diez suele alternar el empleo de cifras o palabras en la indicación de los porcentajes: El 3% (o tres por ciento) de los encuestados dijo no estar de acuerdo con la medida. El símbolo % debe leerse siempre «por ciento», no «por cien», salvo en el caso del 100%, que puede expresarse en letras de tres modos: cien por cien, cien por ciento o ciento por ciento (→ ciento, 3). (...)

Por tanto, lo correcto sería eliminar el espacio y dejarlo en:

> **12%** superior general

Comment: Me imagino que nadie va a discutir este punto. ¿No convendría que vaya en la publicación de mejoras de traducciones?

Comment: @Mariano estuve dudando de si publicarlo allí o no. Finalmente opté por no hacerlo porque no me pareció un error de traducción (en SO no hay espacio entre N y %), sino estilística. Pero vaya, si se mueve allí no me parecerá nada mal, la cuestión es que lo vea Konaniman :)

Comment: Estoy buscando esa cadena...en cuanto la encuentre, la edito para que luzca mejor. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se ha corregido este problema. Solo esperen un breve tiempo desde la publicación de esta respuesta para que la base de datos se actualize.

Comment: Qué bien, gracias Juan M. Ahora tenemos un espacio extra disponible para hacer con él lo que queramos :)